# TypeError when running pyTMX in pycharm (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror, pytmx

I am trying to use pyGame and pyTMX in pyCharm; however, I am getting an annoying error message whenever I try to run the program.
The following code was

```
def get_tile_properties(self, x, y, layer):
    """ Return the tile image GID for this location
    :param x: x coordinate
    :param y: y coordinate
    :param layer: layer number
    :rtype: python dict if found, otherwise None
    """
    try:
        assert (x >= 0 and y >= 0 and layer >= 0)
    except AssertionError:
        raise ValueError

    try:
        gid = self.layers[int(layer)].data[int(y)][int(x)]
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        msg = "Coords: ({0},{1}) in layer {2} is invalid."
        logger.debug(msg.format(x, y, layer))
        raise Exception

    else:
        try:
            return self.tile_properties[gid]
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            msg = "Coords: ({0},{1}) in layer {2} has invalid GID: {3}"
            logger.debug(msg.format(x, y, layer, gid))
            raise Exception
        except KeyError:
            return None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tett/Documents/Vietnam/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    properties = tmxdata.get_tile_properties(x, y, layer)
  File "C:\Users\tett\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 568, in get_tile_properties
    assert (x >= 0 and y >= 0 and layer >= 0)
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'TiledTileLayer' and 'int'
```

I started learning pyGame two weeks before posting this so I know how tiled maps are way above my skill level. because of that, I copied this and some other code off of the pyTMX website. I believe tiled maps is the next most important thing I need to learn for my game before I move on. The code doesn't seem to work (for me at least) and that is why I am on here to see if anybody has a solution. I looked on Youtube, those tiled map tutorial videos didn't work and my solutions to fix this issue didn't work.

The code I copied to call the pyTMX file looks like this. m1w1.tmx is the file I am trying to load.

```
tmxdata = pytmx.TiledMap("m1w1.tmx")
tiled_map = pytmx.TiledMap('m1w1.tmx')
for layer in tiled_map.layers:
    for x, y, image in layer.tiles():
        for obj in layer:

            # tile ('GID') properties are accessed through the TiledMap:
            properties = tmxdata.get_tile_properties(x, y, layer)
            bbox = obj.x, obj.y, obj.width, obj.height
            points = obj.points
            # if obj.closed == True, then obj is a polygon
```

Comment: Well obviously the `layer` argument isn't a number but an actual layer object.

Comment: That is easy enough to say, but what needs to be changed in my code to get it working?

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense at all. The same map is loaded twice and accessed under different names and the properties are determined for each object in `layer` but they don't change, because `x`, `y`, and `layer` don't change. I somewhat lost what you want to achieve here, so I can't tell what to do.